# MySQL 8 group replication: How to skip some GTID transactions

Tags: mysql, gtid, mysql-group-replication

We have a MySQL 8 replication group. How can we skip some GTID transactions which cause errors on slave.

Comment: [Update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65987910/edit) with the error message(s) received from slave.

Comment: We dropped serveral events which do not exist on slave servers. We solved the problem by stopping replication group,  creating event on slaves (did not write to binlog of slaves) and starting replication group again. Thanks.